# Who is disgusting?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

The students are Alex, Baker, Carol, Daquan, Eugene, Francois, Gilbert, and Hilbert. During a class in session, I claimed that one of the students is disgusting. You only see one clue however:

```
169
```

Who?

There will probably be many ways to stretch an answer to work, clarifications will arrive as needed plus a hint if no one figures it out within the next 3 days. As a preliminary hint, you should not need to torture information out of the clue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's

> Baker

because

> a *gross* is a dozen dozens (that is, 144); 169 would therefore be a "baker's gross" (a [baker's dozen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dozen#Baker%27s_dozen) of baker's dozens).

Comment: Perhaps I should've chosen a more obscure synonym